# typescript has a problem with react-hook-form fieldArray of numbers field name

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

Very long title but essentially there is a `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322) fieldArray.d.ts(7, 5): The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on type 'UseFieldArrayProps<FormValues, never, "id">'` error on the fieldArray definition in react-hook-form that sometimes disappears but is there most of the time and i have no idea why it is there since all examples show it like that and it sometimes without any changes disappears. Does anyone have a clue what the issue is? Why is typescript complaining?

I've tried changing versions, reordering the control and name values (it removed the error once and when i swapped them again it came back and no matter how many times i swapped them around again it stayed there).

It's one of those errors I have not the slightest clue where it's coming from.

Codesandbox link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-list-of-numbers-s6zg2p?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx

Edit: error is specifically on line 35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because `react-hook-form`'s `useFieldArray` hook only supports objects as values. Any other type of value e.g. string or number does not work.

A workaround is to instead of directly trying to store numbers instead store object containing a property named 'value' that holds the number or whatever you wish stored. You can also in the `handleSubmit` function of the form transform the form data received to the desired one.

```
function transformData(data) {
    return {
        ...data,
        numberArray: data.numberArray.map(nobj => nobj.value)
    }
}

<form 
    onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
        const transformed = transformData(data);
        onSubmit(transformed);
    })}
>
    ... 
<form/>
```

The issue is discussed here: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/7586

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the version of react-hook-form. I checked above code and on updating version it worked fine. Also it was later fixed here
https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/4f52102e52434ab81385856bbf81561b3253c3cb/src/types/fieldArray.ts

Comment: What version are you talking about? The "latest" 7.40.0 causes many other type errors with most things being typed to any. Which is the reason I went back to a version I've used before and did not have that problem. Until I encountered the one this post is about. Edit: here is a link to a fork with that version https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-list-of-numbers-rhf-v-7-40-0-f60s48